# Making a graphical flashlight in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was wondering how can anyone make graphics such as this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.surpax.ledflashlight.panel in android. By graphics iam referring to the interface. Did he use the eclipse or another tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you contact the developer and ask him/her? There is a link to email the developer in the link you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably used Eclipse for the programming, and created the images separately. The images are saved in multiple resolution and used automatically based on the resolution of the device. The images are easily added to the project by referring to them in the XML.

Comment: "_Probably used Eclipse for the programming_" What makes you say that? There are many other IDEs out there and you don't even have to use one, you can just use a text editor. I'm curious which part led you to believe this app was written in Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah ok, but how he did the button animation to open the flashlight?

Comment: Takendarkk, yes. @Tony, I'm sorry, I don't understand your question?